Show that every finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra can be faithfully represented on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space

Show that every finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra can be faithfully represented on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space.
[Hint: Show that finitely many states suffice for the Gelfand-Naimark theorem.]

So, I'm stuck on this one. I kind of see how it works, but can't figure out some details. So, let's say our $C^*$-algebra $A$ is generated by $n$ elements $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n$.
For each $a_i$, there is a state $f_i$ such that $|f_i(a_i^*a_i)|  = \|a_i\|^2$ and then by GNS construction we can find a representation $\pi i$ such that $\|\pi i(a_i)\| = \|a_i\|$. Then we take the direct sum of these representations which give us a representation $\pi$ on a finite sum of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces (each Hilbert space is just a quotient of $A$ itself, so it's finite-dimensional).
Now, I'm not sure how to prove the hint. How do I show that these $n$ representations are "enough"?
Say I take a random element of $A$, which will be of the form $\lambda_ia_i + \dots + \lambda_na_n$. How do I show that $\|\pi(a)\| = \|a\|$? Or alternatively, that $\pi$ is faithful?

In fact, there is a single state $\varphi$ s.t. the GNS representation $\pi_\varphi$ is faithful. Indeed, we observe the following two facts: for any state $\varphi$, $N_\varphi = \{x \in A: \varphi(x^\ast x) = 0\}$ is a proper subspace of $A$ (in fact, a left ideal, but we don’t need that). Also, for any $x \in A$, $x \neq 0$, there exists a state $\varphi$ s.t. $\varphi(x^\ast x) \neq 0$. Now, we start with an arbitrary state $\varphi_1$. Assume $\varphi_n$ has been constructed. If $N_{\varphi_n} \neq \{0\}$, then we may choose a nonzero $x \in N_{\varphi_n}$, then a state $\psi$ s.t. $\psi(x^\ast x) \neq 0$. Let $\varphi_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(\varphi_n + \psi)$. Then $N_{\varphi_{n+1}} = N_{\varphi_n} \cap N_\psi \subsetneq N_{\varphi_n}$, as $x \in N_{\varphi_n}$ but $x \notin N_\psi$. Thus, we have a sequence of strictly decreasing subspaces $N_{\varphi_1} \supsetneq N_{\varphi_2} \supsetneq \cdots$. As $A$ is finite-dimensional, this sequence must terminate. That is, $N_{\varphi_n} = \{0\}$ for some $n$. Set $\varphi = \varphi_n$.
Now, $\pi_\varphi$ is a finite-dimensional representation since $H_\varphi$ is the completion of $A/N_\varphi = A$ under the inner product induced by $\varphi$, and the latter space is finite-dimensional. It is faithful as for any $x \in A$, $x \neq 0$, we have $\|\pi(x) \hat{1}\|_{H_\varphi}^2 = \varphi(x^\ast x) \neq 0$, as $N_\varphi = \{0\}$. In particular, $\pi(x) \neq 0$.

I should also point out that while your original argument is in the correct direction, it cannot work as is. For example, $A = \mathbb{C}^2$, $a_1 = (1, 0)$, $a_2 = (1, 1)$, then you can choose $\pi_1 = \pi_2$ be the one-dimensional representation given by projection onto the first coordinate. You do have $|\pi_i(a_i)| = |a_i|$, but $\pi_1 \oplus \pi_2$ is not faithful (we have $\pi(0, 1) = 0$).

This is assuming your $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ actually span $A$. If they only generate $A$ (as a $C^\ast$-algebra), the situation is even worse. In particular, a finitely generated $C^\ast$-algebra needs not even be finite-dimensional.

Oh yeah, I meant "spanned", not "generated". That makes sense, thank you!

@franciscopires Remember to accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Here is an argument. Consider the centre $Z(A)$ of $A$. It is a finite-dimensional abelian C$^*$-algebra. Being abelian, $Z(A)=C(X)$ for $X$ locally compact; being finite-dimensional, $X$ is finite. Say $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Looking at the functions $1_{\{x_j\}}$ we obtain projections $p_1,\ldots,p_n\in Z(A)$ that are pairwise orthogonal ($p_kp_j=0$ if $k\ne j$), are minimal in $Z(A)$, and add to the identity.
Let $A_j=p_jA$. Since $p_j$ is central, $A_j$ is a C$^*$-algebra. If $J\subset A_j$ is an ideal, it is a finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra inside $A_j$, so it has a unit, which is a projection $q$ in $A_j$. It follows that $J=qA_j$. We also have $J=A_jq$. So for any $a\in A_j$ there exists $b\in A_j$ with $qa=bq$. Then $qa=bq=(bq)q=qaq$. If $a=a^*$, taking adjoints we get $qa=aq$, and as selfadjoint elements span all of $A_j$, $qa=aq$ for all $a\in A_j$. It follows that $q\in Z(A)$ and $q\leq p_j$, so either $q=0$ or $q=p_j$. So $A_j$ is simple.
Let $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ be nonzero states of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ respectively, and $\pi_j$ the GNS representation for $\varphi_j$. As $A_j$ is simple, $\pi_j$ is faithful (for $\ker\pi_j$ is an ideal in $A_j$). From $\dim A_j<\infty$ we have that $H_j=A_j$ is finite-dimensional. Let $\pi:A\to\bigoplus_j H_j$ be given by
$$
\pi(a)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(\pi_1(p_1ap_1\,x_1,\ldots,\pi_n(p_nap_n\,x_n)).
$$
Then $\pi$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $A$ and $\ker\pi=\bigcap_j\ker\pi_j=\{0\}$, so $\pi$ is faithful.
The above argument is part of how one proves that a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ is canonically isomorphic to $\bigoplus_j M_{k_j}(\mathbb C)$.
